# Cannot open the event or launch the Calendar app after create an event programming?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-calendar cordova/phonegap plugin to create events. The events were created (I tested in emulator). However clicking the event in Calendar will always crash the calendar app. The following is the debug output.

I tried to stop the calendar app and then clear the data and it didn't help. When sideloading to a phone, the Calendar app cannot launch at all. Is it bug of the calendar app since the data written from 3rd party plugins can crush the app?

The following is the javascript code I used to create the events.

```
$scope.addCalendar = function (title, eventLocation, notes, startDate, endDate) {//, success, error) {
    //var success = function (message) { console.log("Success: " + JSON.stringify(message)); };
    //var error = function (message) { console.error("Error: " + message); };
    //window.plugins.calendar.createCalendar("Test calendar", success, error);
    var s = new Date(startDate);
    var e = new Date(endDate);
    window.plugins.calendar.createEvent(title, eventLocation, notes, s, e,
        function (result) { console.log('Event created.'); },
        function (err) { console.error("There was an error "+ err); }
        ); //, success, error);
};
```

**Debug output:**

```
I/ActivityManager( 1500): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.calendar/events/3 flg=0x20020000 cmp=com.android.calendar/.EventInfoActivity (has extras)} from uid 10018 on display 0
I/InputDispatcher( 1500): Dropping event because there is no touchable window at (869, 499).
I/InputDispatcher( 1500): Dropping event because there is no touchable window at (869, 499).
I/WebViewFactory( 5558): Loading com.android.webview version 37 (2882263-x86) (code 100007)
I/LibraryLoader( 5558): Loading: webviewchromium
I/LibraryLoader( 5558): Time to load native libraries: 1 ms (timestamps 5605-5606)
I/LibraryLoader( 5558): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider( 5558): Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {87cf21c}
I/LibraryLoader( 5558): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
I/chromium( 5558): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(106)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I/BrowserStartupController( 5558): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
W/art     ( 5558): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
W/chromium( 5558): [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(315)] locale_file_path.empty()
I/chromium( 5558): [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(63)] Load from apk succesful, fd=42 off=46092 len=2953
I/chromium( 5558): [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(78)] Loading webviewchromium.pak from, fd:43 off:228796 len:643667
W/AudioManagerAndroid( 5558): Requires BLUETOOTH permission
I/InputDispatcher( 1500): Dropping event because there is no touchable window at (869, 499).
I/InputDispatcher( 1500): Dropping event because there is no touchable window at (869, 499).
I/ActivityManager( 1500): Displayed com.android.calendar/.EventInfoActivity: +251ms
E/DatabaseUtils( 2131): Writing exception to parcel
E/DatabaseUtils( 2131): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 2 is null
E/DatabaseUtils( 2131):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:164)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2131):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2131):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2131):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2131):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:400)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2131):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:333)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2131):     at com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarProvider2.query(CalendarProvider2.java:1062)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2131):     at com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarProvider2.queryInternal(CalendarProvider2.java:1033)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2131):     at com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarProvider2.query(CalendarProvider2.java:839)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2131):     at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:950)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2131):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:210)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2131):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2131):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
W/AsyncQuery( 5558): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 2 is null
D/AndroidRuntime( 5558): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 5558): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 5558): Process: com.android.calendar, PID: 5558
E/AndroidRuntime( 5558): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime( 5558):    at com.android.calendar.EventInfoFragment$QueryHandler.onQueryComplete(EventInfoFragment.java:536)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5558):    at com.android.calendar.AsyncQueryService.handleMessage(AsyncQueryService.java:412)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5558):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5558):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5558):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5558):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5558):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5558):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
W/ActivityManager( 1500):   Force finishing activity com.android.calendar/.EventInfoActivity
W/ActivityManager( 1500):   Force finishing activity com.android.calendar/.AllInOneActivity
D/DropBoxEntryAddedChimeraService( 2216): User is not opted-in to Usage & Diagnostics.
I/OpenGLRenderer( 1500): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
W/ActivityManager( 1500): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{308c7753 u0 com.android.calendar/.EventInfoActivity t33 f}
I/Process ( 5558): Sending signal. PID: 5558 SIG: 9
W/AudioTrack( 1500): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
I/WindowState( 1500): WIN DEATH: Window{251673fd u0 com.android.calendar/com.android.calendar.EventInfoActivity}
W/libprocessgroup( 1500): failed to open /acct/uid_10018/pid_5558/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
I/ActivityManager( 1500): Process com.android.calendar (pid 5558) has died
I/WindowState( 1500): WIN DEATH: Window{2fede9b6 u0 com.android.calendar/com.android.calendar.AllInOneActivity}
W/InputMethodManagerService( 1500): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 5558 uid 10018
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 2 is null  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference

Comment: Yes I read this too. But it gives no information what exact is null

Comment: Have you tried clearing all the events in calendar?

Comment: Yes tried to delete all the  events created by the plugin.

Comment: I tried it on my android phone, everything's fine. Can you try it on other android device?

Comment: It was tried on two physical phones and one emulator and they all have the issues as described. Maybe it's the values? I will try to modify the values when debugging see if it will resolve the issues

Comment: If the issue persists, could you share a basic demo that can reproduce this problem?